# Search entire everything for string

Tags: python, search

how would I given an object, such as a string, search all global and local everything recursively for a certain object, and then have it return how I would access that object. Sort of like

```
>>> SearchEveryThing(Object_Thing)
Found in global
dictionary_thing[list_thing][2].attribute_thing is Object_Thing
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct was to tell you to somehow use [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) and [`object_instance.__dict__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#) for this, iterating over all the values found but your question is generally something that doesn't really get done.

Imagine if your program was a bigger app. The amount of objects you'd have to iterate over would make this very tricky to handle.

Comment: .__dict__ doesn't work for builtin objects, making it harder if it is hidden away in a list or other builtin container (probably don't have to go through their attributes though.) Iterating won't work with dictionary like things (since it won't hit the keys.)

Comment: You could add special methods for builtins, I suppose. Couldn't you try calling `iteritems` if you're looking to go through 'em all?

Comment: Okay, I found what I was trying to find (I needed a method, so this wouldn't help) but I will remember this for the future.